# Need help changing chatflow so that one number can text multiple times

Tags: twilio-api, twilio-studio

Currently, if a number texts into my chatflow, they are not able to text in again, I don't know how to change that

I am currently trying to remake the flow without the single vs multiple entry split off without breaking it.

This is the current flow.

[image: Chatflow image]

Comment: It would be helpful to know what you've tried so far. I.e. adding a screenshot of you current studio flow and the user interaction that you did with this flow.

Comment: Trying to attach some screenshots right now, I basically tried to edit out the "send single entry" and "send multiple entry" options and just make that one unified option, but I can't seem to get it to work @iobert

Answer (score 0):

When you have a Studio flow, and you are able to trigger it once, but not for a second time, probably you have a stuck execution.

This could occur when you receive an event that Twilio wasn’t expecting, for example, you receive a message while you were executing a function, etc.
In this reference, you can learn how to find and stop these executions:
https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115016032048-Troubleshooting-Issues-with-Twilio-Studio

After that, check the execution logs to understand what caused the issue.

When this issue occurs, you receive the warning 81002:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/81002

In the picture it is not possible to see very well the single and multiple entry feature that you are trying to build, feel free to open a ticket with Twilio if you need additional help.